# Java sqlite update statement

Tags: java, sqlite

## "Is this statement correct? it cannot pass my JUnit test!!!"

What is wrong with my statement?

It doesnt pass the JUnit test.

`String sqlStringLockWithIP = "UPDATE ACCOUNTS SET " + "LOCKSTATE = "+1+" , " + "IPADDRESS = "+ipAddress+" WHERE ID = " + id;`

Comment: What is your JUnit test?

Comment: You tell us. How would we know? What's the type of the `IPADDRESS` column and the `ipAddress` variable? Also, why bother concatenating the `1` and the other adjacent string?

Comment: ipAddress = "7'; drop table ACCOUNTS; " :-)

Comment: You're appending a lot of strings where they don't need to be, your syntax looks correct, please post your stacktrace, also, using PreparedStatements is always highly recommended with SQL

Comment: I just need like the answer below, correct my statement.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean:

```
String sqlStringLockWithIP = "UPDATE ACCOUNTS SET LOCKSTATE = 1, IPADDRESS = '"+ipAddress+"' WHERE ID = " + id;
```